# Can I rebuild a package without recompiling the source?

Tags: dpkg, compiling

I am building a new .deb and want to fix lintian errors in the packaging.  However, every time I rebuild, the rules file does a 'make clean' and thus starts compiling again.

Is there a way to instruct the build process that I do not want to recompile, that I'm just altering the packaging, and using the last set of binaries will be fine for now?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That depends on how you're building the package. `dpkg-buildpackage` doesn't call the `clean` target if you pass it the `-nc` option. Another useful option for test build is `-uc` (don't sign the changes file). `debuild` inherits these options from `dpkg-buildpackage`.

For a test build, you can simply do `fakeroot debian/rules binary` (adjust the target as appropriate for a multiple-binary package).

Answer (score 8):

Using [`ccache`](http://ccache.samba.org/), you can build the package as normal, without actually recompiling unchanged source files.

`ccache` works by storing old results of compilations, and only rebuilds if the source actually changed.

```
debuild --prepend-path=/usr/lib/ccache --preserve-envvars=CCACHE_*
```

Comment: I got `dpkg-buildpackage: unknown option or argument --preserve-envvars=CCACHE_*` but I removed that option, seems to work ok without it